# ViewController init?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have just noticed that my ViewController does not call init (See below) when it starts up.

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSLog(@"_init: %@", [self class]);
        otherStuff...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there a reason for this, or is it replaced by viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    otherStuff ..
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

cheers gary

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not replaced by `viewDidLoad`. It's just that init's not called by `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

I just write my setup code in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Your answer is actually useful to me!

Answer (score 5):

If your view controller is being initialized from a storyboard, then you can use:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // do init here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

awakeFromNib is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

- (void) init works fine if you create the object in code, but you DO have to make sure it's the one you call.  It doesn't do any good to flesh out the templated initWithNibName:bundle: method and then call the other one.